# Гибкая настройка редиректов в Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

Помогите пожалуйста с настройкой. На сайте изменилось множество URL, и чтобы не потерять трафик нужно грамотно раскидать трафик по страницам.

Гуглил, но ничего похожего не нашел...
Итак, есть ссылки которые надо привести к следующему виду:

> /divany-i-kresla => /myagkaya-mebel; (категория)
>
> /divany-i-kresla/kresla-kachalki => /myagkaya-mebel/kresla; (категория 2 уроввня)

Но также могут быть товары и тут /divany-i-kresla/product_1 и тут /divany-i-kresla/kresla-kachalki/product_2 (т.е. мы заранее не знаем чем закончится url, однако итоговый список подкатегорий составить можно)

А есть и посложнее задача из этой оперы:

> /komplekty-mebeli => /myagkaya-mebel
>
> /komplekty-mebeli/mebel-dlya-gostinoj => /gostinye/gostinye-garnitury;

Т.е. "комлекты мебели" являются "мягкой мебелью", а вот многоуровневые "комплекты мебели" рассматриваются персонально (в зависимости от url). И также в конце каждой категории могут быть товары (т.е. неизвестный набор символов). Надо чтобы и ссылки на категории редиректились корректно и на товары тоже.

Кстати еще наверное стоит привести все url к одному типу: либо со / на конце, либо без него.

И еще, для удобства я в основной файл конфига внес такую запись:

```
include /etc/nginx/vhosts/neuroz/redirect-map.conf;
server {
...
if ($redirect_uri) {
    return 301 $redirect_uri;
}
}
```

И соответственно создал redirect-map.conf, где собираюсь прописать великое множество подобных редиректов. Мне бы только пример показать...

```
map $uri $redirect_uri {
#мои ридеректы
}
```

Comment: Проще написать на php или какой там у вас серверный язык. Впрочем у вас же уже практически всё написано. Осталось map наполнить

Comment: Спасибо про совет на PHP ! Че-то сам не догадался... Жаль только производительность - системе придется всё же обработать часть ненужного кода из CMS непосредственно перед переадресацией.
А что касается "наполнить map" - в этом и есть весь вопрос. Я не знаю какие нужно писать регулярки, чтобы реализовать описанные выше задачи...